# date math with curdate

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I need to perform a select where my `lpdt7` is within 7 days of today.
Code below returns: "Value in date, time, or timestamp string not valid."

```
SELECT lnmast.sname,
       lnmast.status,
       ddmast.acctno,
       ddmast.status,
       date(digits(lpdt7)) AS closed
FROM mydat.lnmast lnmast
LEFT OUTER JOIN mydat.ddmast ddmast ON lnmast.cifno = ddmast.cifno
AND lnmast.altadd = ddmast.altadd
WHERE lnmast.status = 2
  AND date(digits(lpdt7)) >= curdate() -7 days
```

Comment: Just before doing any deeper investigation for this problem, have you looked at [the ibm sql error](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21349843)

Comment: What is the format of the date in `lpdt7`?

Comment: Decimal(7,0), OK. But what does the data look like? How is a date represented? For example, is it mmddyy, yymmdd, cyymmdd?  The best solution may involve creating a UDF, but we need to properly understand your data first, to give you the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error guys.  I had to trap for null values in the date field first.

```
WHERE lnmast.status = 2 and lpdt7 > 1 and date(digits(lpdt7)) >= curdate() - 7 days
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, now you can check your answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

I think date function does not work with decimal like date(digits(lpdt7)) and causing error that you see.
Assuming your decimal date in YYYYMMDD format.  You can convert it like this.

```
 DATE (SUBSTR ( DIGITS (lpdt7) , 1 , 4 ) || '-' || 
       SUBSTR ( DIGITS (lpdt7) , 5 , 2 ) || '-' || 
       SUBSTR ( DIGITS (lpdt7) , 7 , 2 ) )
```

I'm using DIGITS instead of CHAR because it does not suppress 0.
It is better to create date conversion functions in you system - sql codes will looks much cleaner. This answer was taken from part of date function used in our live system.